# Betta laying at bottom of the tank

Tags: betta

I got a male betta yesterday, and moved him into his 2.5 gallon tank today. I read multiple sites that said it was okay to move him within 24 hours of setting the tank up. The filter is working, and the heater is too. The temp says it is 78 degrees F. We put the conditioner in the water when we filled the tank up yesterday, so it sat for 24 hours with the filter on. I also checked the pH, nitrate, nitrite, and a few other factors of the tank which all came back as perfect. We moved him into the tank like we were supposed to, and he seemed to assimilate nicely to the new tank. When I sit by the tank, he usually comes straight up to me and then swims around. There's only one plant in there for him now, but I will be getting more tomorrow. I got the silk fake plants recommended for Bettas. I left the light on in the tank and turned the light off in my room, leaving him for about an hour. Half an hour in I checked on him and he was by the filter (he was just hanging out by it, it's not too strong and he wasn't stuck). Then when I came back in a half an hour later he was in the corner of the tank between the plant and wall. He was laying on the gravel between the two, not stuck though. It took him a minute, but he swam up to me and now he's swimming around okay. Is this normal for them to do? His fins look alright, and he doesn't appear to be breathing rapidly or have an ich on him. I've fed him flakes today, which he doesn't go for immediately but he will eat them. I'm getting pellets soon also. Is he just stressed from the move, or is there something more serious going on? This is the first betta I've owned so I just want to make sure he's doing okay and nothing else is happening to him.

Comment: I don't think it's your issue but it does take 6-8 weeks for a tank to be ready before you can use it for fish.